How to negate custom function return value? in json-logic
I have custom function that simply returns boolean value for the json-logic
const customFunction = (rule, data) => true

and here is my rule
{
  "and": [
    {
      "!": {
        "customFunction": [
          ["math"],
          {
            "var": "STUDENT.CLASSROOM.SUB"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

The custom function is working well and giving the right answer true. The issue is that when i try to negate using !, it's still returning true instead of false, which is not what I expect.
can you help me trace the problem?


apologies for tagging 'javascript' as there are only 11 viewers in 'json-logic', couldn't find closest related tag.


Not sure about the library you are using but the custom function you show will always return true no matter what is passed. Should you be calling jsonLogic.apply instead of you custom method?

yes. im calling jsonLogic.apply. I found the cause though. thanks

stated here the custom function has limitation https://jsonlogic.com/add_operation.html . solution i got is to do the negate inside the customFunction.
